# How to Make < and > As Actual Text Symbols and Not Tags Within HTML

Tags: html, text, special-characters

Whenever I type "<", it gets mistaken as the beginning of a tag. How could I use that character as actual text such as in a paragraph so that it would appear like "<"?

Comment: See [HTML Codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Here is more information on other [html encodings](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You use the actual entity names like this:

```
<p>&#60</p>
<p>&#62</p>
```

It will show this in the console

<
>

Read this article about HTML entities, it should help!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp